# First-year matrix problem: How do you show that a sum of an identity matrix and another matrix is equal to the sum's inverse?

Tags: matrices, inverse

The following is the problem at hand:

$A^4 = 2A^2.$ Prove that $(I-A^2) = (I-A^2)^{-1}$

My attempts at a solution:

$I = A^{-1} * A,$ therefore we can start with $(A^{-1}A - A^2) = (A^{-1}A - (1/2)A^4) = (A^{-1}A - A^2) = (A^{-1}A - (1/2)(A^{-4})^{-1}) = ???$

I'm having problems with the fundamentals of this question. Sure, I can play around with the individual matrices on the left side, but that doesn't help to handle the inverse of a sum of matrices, like how the transpose of a sum is equal to the sum of the transpose of its individual matrix terms. How do you approach this without delving into more complex matrix operations?

Comment: Hint: you do not have to actually find any inverse in this problem.  If I say "$C$ is the inverse of $B$", what does that actually mean?

Comment: @David Oh right! That means that their product equals the identity matrix, so (I - A^2)(I - A^2). I wouldn't be able to distribute that, would I?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is distributive over addition.  It's not always commutative though

Comment: With respect to J.W. Tanner's comment: Although in general, matrices $A$ and $B$ do not commute, the identity matrix *will* commute with any other matrix, and of course any matrix commutes with itself.

Comment: For the record, I agree with @BrianTung's elaboration of my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(I-A^2)(I-A^2)=I\times I - I \times A^2 - A^2 \times I + A^2 \times A^2 $$

$$=I - A^2 - A^2 + A^4 = I - 2A^2 + A^4,$$

so this is $I$ if $A^4=2A^2,$

so $(I-A^2)^{-1}=(I-A^2)$ in that case.

Comment: This would work in any ring, which has a distributive law, not just matrices. Multiplicative inverse of a sum is not generally easy to work with algebraically